# Select the keys if value of a field is "auto"

Tags: jq

I have a JSON file which I am trying to parse. I want to select the key value if the value of a field is `auto`. I should get output as `package2`. I use `jq` to parse JSON in the `bash` shell.

```json
{
    "package1":{
        "name":"package_1",
        "value":"manual"
    },
    "package2":{
        "name":"package_2",
        "value":"auto"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

With

```bash
jq 'map_values(select(.value == "auto"))' file
```

... you pull out the parts of the top-level object that you are interested in:

```json
{
  "package2": {
    "name": "package_2",
    "value": "auto"
  }
}
```

With `map_values(expression)`, you apply `expression` to each sub-part of the input object. In this case, the part is *kept* if the test in the `select()` statement evaluates to *true*, and discarded otherwise.  It's similar to `map(expression)`, but you'd use `map()` on arrays and `map_values()` on objects.

From there, you can choose to get the top-level key:

```bash
$ jq -r 'map_values(select(.value == "auto"))|keys[]' file
package2
```

The `keys` function creates an array of all keys in the input object, and the `[]` at the end expands the array into a set of strings.

Note that if there are multiple sub-objects with `auto` as their `.value` key's value, you will get multiple strings out of this command.

---

For a brief moment, I was unsure whether you wanted the value of the `.name` key or the top-level key.  Once I spotted that you only wanted the top-level key, I had already written the text below.  I'm leaving it in as a sort of comment.

```bash
$ jq -r 'map_values(select(.value == "auto"))[].name' file
package_2
```

Using `[].name` at the end, expand the top-level object into a set of sub-objects and then extract the `.name` key's value from each.

This last one could also have been written

```bash
$ jq -r 'map_values(select(.value == "auto").name)[]' file
package_2
```

... which reduces the original object to only

```json
{
  "package2": "package_2"
}
```

... and then extracts the values of all remaining keys with the trailing `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jq's [select()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)) function:

```
jq -r '.[] | select(.value=="auto").name'
```

Also your json example is currently invalid.

Comment: Note that they are expecting `package2`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I see.  Potentially an x-y issue though, In most cases the only reason to want that key is in order to use it to retrieve it's object which would be an unnecessary extra step.

Comment: <shrug> Storing actual data in _keys_ is something I'm personally avoiding. I would say they would benefit from using an array instead, with an extra key+value in each element, or just a set of free floating JSON objects (with an extra key+value in each). But maybe they want to uniquify the list and they do that by using a "hash". I dunno, it's a mystery.